# Where am I going wrong in solving this ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve an ODE but seems that I am making some mistakes. I would appreciate any help.

$$
y'' + \frac{3}{x} y' = x
$$
I substituted

$ z(x) =  y'$

So equation becomes
$$ z' + \frac{3}{x} z = x $$

This is linear first order ODE.
Integrating factor

$$
 IF = {e}^{\int \frac{3}{x} \mathrm{d}x }\ = x^3
$$ 
Solution of DE is
$$ y x^3 = \int x x^3 \mathrm{d}x + c
\implies y x^3 = \frac{x^5}{5} +c
 $$

When I back-substitute y, it doesn't satisfy the equation. So something is going wrong here, but I can't find what or where. Any help, much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in the substitution. Corrected the equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

substituted

$ z(x) =  y'$

So equation becomes
$$ z' + \frac{3}{x} z = x $$

This is linear first order ODE.
Integrating factor

$$
 IF = {e}^{\int \frac{3}{x} \mathrm{d}x }\ = x^3
$$ 
Solution of DE is
$$z x^3 = \int x x^3 \mathrm{d}x + c
\implies z x^3 = \frac{x^5}{5} +c
 $$
therefore you must change $y$ to $z$. Now consider $ z =  y'$ from here I hope you can continue